# Freeciv (Macports SDL) can't create scorelog

Tags: macos, freeciv

I'm playing Freeciv 2.4.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (Mavericks), using the SDL client from MacPorts package `freeciv @2.4.2_0+universal`

Whenever I start by loading a game, I get the message **`Can't open scorelog file 'freeciv-score.log' for creation!`**

**How do I make it possible for Freeciv to create this file?**

It seems to be the server that tries to create the file, but I haven't been able to find the full path it uses, or any server configuration file that might control the path it uses.  There's no apparent problem with client files `~/.freeciv-client-rc-2.4` or `~/.freeciv/*`, or with game data in `/opt/local/share/freeciv/*`.